# Unexploded WAR Tomcat performance

Tags: tomcat

I'm trying to determine the difference in Tomcat 7 performance for exploded vs. unexploded WAR.

Which is faster - exploded or unexploded mode?

And what's the impact on loading resources from the classpath?

=== EDIT ===

Never mind - I found out Tomcat always explodes the WAR, so there really is no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomcat always explodes the WAR, so there really is no difference at run time.